# Getting error in SSIS execute SQL Task for MySQL

Tags: ssis

I am running SSIS >> Execute SQL task with Direct sql Statement , connected to **MySQL** via ADO.Net as

```
CREATE TABLE Test_abc (
task_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

Insert into Test_abc(title) values('abc');
```

[image: Execute SQL Task]

but when I run the package, following error is displayed

> Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly,
> parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

**Please note that If I write only one SQL ie either Create or Insert , it will work but I want to execute Create and Insert statement in only one Execute SQL task.**

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding a semicolon after the CREATE TABLE command when you are attempting to do both together? In your example script I see the semicolon at the end of the INSERT statement, but they are technically two separate commands and MySQL might complain

Comment: Yes I tried adding semicolon as well and it didn't even work but when I used 'GO' statement at the end it worked. I am confused does 'Execute SQL task' have its own limitations in executing the sql when works fine in MySQL workbench.

Comment: That may be the problem--inside the SQL Task, SSIS might be using TSQL instead of MySQL, and using GO is an acceptable keyword in TSQL

Comment: but having semicolon in between Create and insert should also work as in theory semicolon between two queries is also a valid TSQL.
My issue is I have very large .sql file that I have to Execute and that file has semicolon in between queries.